# how can I position circles and keep them in the same arrangement in a responsive design?

Tags: css, sass

[image: The aim is to create 3 circles in this sort of position]

I'm planning to create a background of a website that contains 3 circles. I can arrange them in a way that I like, However, if I make the browser smaller, circle 2 goes up way to far and the circles become too small, making the distance of the circles too big. I want to keep the arrangement photo-ed on smaller screens. I feel there would be a lot of hassle making loads of media queries, is there a simpler way?

HTML:

```
<main>
<div class="circle"></div>
<div class="circle"></div>
<div class="circle"></div>
</main>
```

CSS:

```
main {
height: 1000px;
background-color: #EEE1FF;
// margin: 10%;
// z-index: -2;
}

.circle {
position: absolute;
width: 60%;
padding-bottom: 60%;
height: auto;
border-radius: 50%;
background: #F4ECFE;
}

.circle:nth-child(1){
    top: -15%;
    left: -15%;
    z-index: 1;
}

.circle:nth-child(2){
    top: -50%;
    left: 55%;
}

.circle:nth-child(3){
    top: 40%;
    left: 35%;
}
```

Comment: You can do this to a certain extent, but devices have different aspect ratios so you'd need to decide what you want it to look like for example in portrait mode, on 'thin' devices etc. What width of device gives you the layout you like when the height is 1000px?

Comment: Thanks for the advice, so I'm aim for something in this res: 1640x1600.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Measuring the given image it looks as though it is sized for a viewport with aspect ratio roughly 16:9. While many devices have this sort of ratio in fact while they are being used they often have a greater ratio because there are browser bars and websites are not necessarily seen in full screen mode. On laptops/desktops the user may have multi windows open of varying dimensions.

The aim will have to be to do 'the best we can' to give the same sort of effect.

This snippet by no means goes all the way to that but is given here to help you get started. It does not at all consider portrait mode as I don't know what sort of effect you want for that. The basic trick is to make all dimensions have relative units - and to remember that 1% of width is not the same as 1% of height. (there is an exception for padding which can be useful where % is always in terms of width but currently this snippet does not use that).

Note - the snippet looks bad when not in full screen mode because it has odd aspect ratio (wide compared to height) and if you wanted to cater for that sort of extreme you would need to think about what you want the result to look like - should the circles be shown more, should the distance between them increase but the circles stay the same size etc.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#main {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
    background-color: #EEE1FF;
    --w: 16;
    --h: 9;
    --width: 100vw;
    --height: 100vh;
    width: var(--width);
    height: var(--height);
height: 100vmin;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.circle {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    
    --cd: 9; /* diameter of a circle */
    --cr: calc(var(--cd) / 2);

    position: absolute;
    left: calc((((var(--cx) - var(--cr))/ var(--w)) * 160vmin));
    top: calc((((var(--cy) - var(--cr)) / var(--w)) * 160vmin));
    
    width: calc((var(--cd) / var(--w)) * 160vmin);
    height: calc((var(--cd) / var(--w)) * 160vmin);
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #F4ECFE;
}

.circle:nth-child(1){
    --cx: 2.5; /* distance of center from the left */
    --cy: 3.3; /* distance of center from the top */
    z-index: 1;
}

.circle:nth-child(2){
    --cx: 13.7;
    --cy: -0.85;
}

.circle:nth-child(3){
    --cx: 10.5;
    --cy: 8.8;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
<div class="circle"></div>
<div class="circle"></div>
<div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no best solution here.

You might use media queries or the css `calc` function to play with a sum of absolute unites and of relative units. You may try someting like ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc())):

```
width: calc(100px + 50%)
```

You can also add a `min-width` property to define a minimum length for your circles.

Comment: Thank you ennoriel, I'll experiment with the calc method tomorrow, I have tried using min and max-width however I can't apply the same to the height as it's made of padding, I've even tried using `padding-bottom: max ( 725px, 60%);`

Answer (score 0):

I found the code way too painful to create, I made a background image and centred it, and stretched the width in a fewer media queries.